# PHP hit counter issue

Tags: php, database

I have 3 php pages.

Counter.php - I want this file to display how many clicks Counter 2, Counter 3 got.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    You visited page Counter2
    <?php include 'Counter2.php'; echo $Counter; ?>
    Times.
    You visited page Counter3
    <?php  include 'Counter3.php'; echo $Counter3; ?>
    Times.
  </body>
</html>
```

Counter2.php - I want to count the amount of click this page has had.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION["counter"]))
  {
    $counter = $_SESSION["counter"];
  }
  else
  {
     $counter = 0;
  }
  $_SESSION["counter"] = $counter + 1;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= $counter ?>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Counter3.php - I want to count the amount of click this page has had.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION["counter3"]))
  {
    $counter3 = $_SESSION["counter3"];
  }
  else
  {
    $counter3 = 0;
  }

  $_SESSION["counter3"] = $counter3 + 1;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  You visted this page this many times:
  <?= $counter3 ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, everything is working how it should be, HOWEVER, when I include the php files `<?php include 'Counter3.php'; echo $Counter3; ?>`
to log the amount of clicks it continues to increase when I load the Counter.php file. I do not want it to, I just want Counter.php to log how many clicks Counter2 and Counter3 has had. 
And stop Counter.php increasing the click number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to add an extra if to both counter2.php and counter3.php, and if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` points to counter.php, you can skip incrementing the counters

Comment: Bit confusing there mate ! I understand what you mean though ! Thanks, for the help.

Comment: I should of write it more clearly, sorry! Anyway, glad to help tough, and if it is no trouble, could you hit the arrow up on the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Including a page makes the code run, so it would increase all the counters in the pages. Instead just use the `$_SESSION[]` variable directly.

```
<?php
  session_start()
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
You visited page Counter2 <?php  echo $_SESSION["counter2"]; ?> Times.
You visited page Counter3 <?php  echo $_SESSION["counter3"]; ?> Times.
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in PHP you can do the following:

```
$_SESSION["counter3"] = isset($_SESSION["counter3"]) ? $_SESSION["counter3"] : 0;
//$_SESSION["counter3"] = $_SESSION["counter3"] ?? 0; // only in PHP 7
```

Also on a side note, you don't have to create this code on every page as it might get messy in the long run.

```
<?php #counter.php
  if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['counter'][$_SEVER['REQUEST_URI']])){
    $_SESSION['counter'][$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']] = $_SESSION['counter'][$_SEVER['REQUEST_URI']] + 1
  } else {
    $_SESSION['counter'][$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']] = 1;
  }

  function countpagetimes(){
    return $_SESSION['counter'][$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];
  }
?>

<?php #somepage.php
  include 'counter.php';

  echo 'You visited this page ' . countpagetimes() . ' times'.

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, do not usally get this, also when you say 'you don't have to create this code on every page', the code your provided me with where do I put it ? In the Counter.php file or Counter2, Counter3 ? And how does it work ? Sorry I am newbie to PHP. Cheers !

Comment: Note the `<?php #counter.php` and the `<?php #somepage.php`

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for this problem:

1. Save both values in a database and access the values through counter.php, instead of including the files
2. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to let the counter only increment if the URI does not contain counter.php